# How do i await cogs in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, discord.py

I was trying to create a discord bot in python that will play music from YouTube. But when i run this script, it shows the bot is online but if i enter a command then it says command not found. gives me this warning everytime i run the script.

```
/bin/python3 "/home/r1d0m/Python/Discord Music Bot/main.py"
/home/r1d0m/Python/Discord Music Bot/main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/home/r1d0m/Python/Discord Music Bot/main.py:16: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
  bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
```

And this is what i coded in main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from help_cog import help_cog

from music_cog import music_cog

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents = intents)

bot.remove_command("help")

bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

with open('/home/r1d0m/Python/Discord Music Bot/token.txt') as redk:
    contents = redk.read()

bot.run(contents)
```

I don't know what to do. please help.

I even tried to add this,

```
await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
```

But it gives me error.

Comment: It's in the migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Try reading up on async-await for python. This is a good starting point.
[Async IO in Python](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/)

`await` should always reside inside an `async` function.

eg snippet:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from help_cog import help_cog

from music_cog import music_cog


async def main():
    ...
    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
    
    with open('/home/r1d0m/Python/Discord Music Bot/token.txt') as redk:
        contents = redk.read()
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())
```